# how to get array random from object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I tried to make array from random item object to get 2 items. I used `array_rand()` but the output is `array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given` and `Trying to get property of non-object`

My code is for get random item is :

```
$k=2;    
$centroid = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$k; $i++){
     $centroid[] = new DataSet($table[array_rand($i)]->sig_class_id,$table[array_rand($i)]->sig_priority);
    }
```

Get data from

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT sig_class_id, sig_priority FROM coba");
  $table=array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
      $table[] = new DataSet($row->sig_class_id, $row->sig_priority);
  }
```

and class DataSet is

```
class DataSet{
  public $sig_class_id;
  public $sig_priority;
  function __construct($sig_class_id, $sig_priority){
    $this->sig_class_id = $sig_class_id;
    $this->sig_priority = $sig_priority;
  }
 }
```

any thought?

Comment: You should pass your array to `array_rand()`, not an integer.

Comment: `array_rand($table)` -- Instead of wasting everyone time read the PHP docs  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php  (lol),  Another thing that will help you is get a good IDE,  I use Eclipse PDT (oxygen) and its free and takes care of all the documentation for you.  Eclipse has come a long way sense I started using it back in `3.4`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in wrong logic. Instead, you should get a random number and get random number related array. Try below code!

```
$random = 0;
$centroid = array();
    for($i=0; $i=2; $i++){
     $random = rand();
     $centroid[] = new DataSet($table[$random]->sig_class_id,$table[$random]->sig_priority);
    }
```

== Edit 1 == 
Tip 1 : You can also use mt_rand() function produces a better random value, and is 4 times faster than rand().

Tip 2 : If you want a random integer between 10 and 100 (inclusive), use rand (10,100).